# How to send parameter to a GET API in another controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have 2 pages. Page 1 is Information page. Page 2 is Status Page. Each page has it own controller (infoController and statusController). On form submit on page1 I have to call a Post API and then navigate to Page2. I also need to send an ID along with it. On page2 I have to use this ID to make a GET request.

```
POST API
/information
RESPONSE
statusCode: "200"
statusMessage: string
agencyId: "ddsdsa"

GET API
/certification/view/{agencyId}
```

## Controller Page1

```
function postData() {
            var dataToSend = {
                agencyName: vm.data.agencyName,
                businessLegalName: vm.data.businessLegalName,
            };
            var postPromise = httpService.apiPostRequest ('/information', dataToSend);
            postPromise.then(function(response){
                if(response.data.statusCode == '200'){
                    $state.go ("accsetup.status");
                    Id = response.data.id;
                }
            })  
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log (error);
            });

        }
```

## Controller Page2

```
function StatusController ($http, httpService) {    
        var vm = this;

        var promise = httpService.apiGetRequest('/certification/view/ddsdsa');
        promise.then(function(response){
            vm.data = response.data;
        })  
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log (error);
        });

    }
```

Comment: So um what is the problem you're having?

Comment: @ Maria Ines Parnisari - I need to pass the agencyId: "ddsdsa" to the GET API which is in another controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *Information page* you can use `$state.go` to send data to the new view.

```
if (response.data.statusCode == '200'){
    var agencyId = response.data.id; // e.g. ddsdsa
    $state.go("accsetup.status", {agencyId: agencyId});        
}
```

Then in your *Status page* you retrieve this value with the `$stateParams` service of [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).

```
function StatusController ($http, $stateParams, httpService) {    
    var vm = this;
    var agencyId = $stateParams.agencyId; // ddsdsa
    var promise = httpService.apiGetRequest('/certification/view/' + agencyId );
    // etc
}
```

For this to work you need to update your state definition:

```
.state('accsetup.status', {
  params: {agencyId: null} // add this
})
```

Comment: $state.go("accsetup.status", {agencyId: agencyId});    pull in the value. But when it goes to StatusCroller agencyId is undefined

Comment: Inside the `StatusController`, can you put a breakpoint in the line `var agency = ...` and tell me what you see in `$stateParams`?

Comment: yes. i did that. It is showing undefined. Below is how i defined my route

Comment: .state('accsetup.agencyinfo', {
                url: '/information/view/:agencyId',
                templateUrl: '/agencyinfo.html',
                controller: 'InfoController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                bindToController: true,
                params: {agencyId: null}
            })

Comment: Huh? That state `accsetup.agency.agencyinfo` is not using `StatusController`. You need to update the state for `accsetup.status`!